# Passing a variable between Xib's for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, integer, xib

[image]in my app I have 21 Xib's and on each of them there is a button that randomly generates to open another one of the 21 Xib's.

There is a countdown timer from 10 to find this button.

For example, if the user finds the button in 7 seconds, I would like 7 seconds to add to the next Xib's countdown, making it 17 seconds.

Also, I would like the user to have a point system - From my previous example, I would like the user to gain 7 points and have be seen on the next Xib that randomly appears.

Thank you

Comment: what is the question, please elaborate what do you need and also provide a sample of your code?

Comment: Side note - please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Why do you have 21 xibs? What is different from one to the next? What do you have in these views besides the button? It's not clear from your explanation why you can't do this with just one view controller.

Answer (score 1):

As you want `value` for `entire application` then use `NSUserDefaults` and use `same key` to `access` anywhere

```
//totalcount is key here it can be any string you want to have
//Firstly set timer to 10
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:10 forKey:@"totalcount"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

`Update` value like this:

```
NSInteger totalCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"totalcount"];
totalCount + = yourRemaingSecondshere;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:totalCount forKey:@"totalcount"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Note : Always use NSUserDefaults's totalcount for as count timer**

Comment: Agree with this. One of the many ways to do this! This is equivalent to SharedPreferences in Android OS.

Comment: Here is my code for my countdown timer.  What could if my mainInt reaches 7? Could I say if (mainInt == 7) { //pass 7 to next countdown }

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    mainInt = 10;
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(myCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: -(void)myCountdown {
    
    mainInt -= 1;
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mainInt];
    if (mainInt ==0) {
        FailurePage *failure = [[FailurePage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
         [self presentViewController:failure animated:YES completion:NULL];
    
    }

Comment: i am not getting it what exactly you want to do here??

Comment: I want to pass an integer from the countdown and add it to the next countdown that loads.

Comment: For example, if the user finds the button on the Xib at 4 seconds, I would like the remaining 4 seconds to add to the next Xib's countdown, making the next countdown 14 seconds

Comment: This use is really not what user defaults are for; their intended use is to persist data between launches of an app. It would be easy enough to pass the number of seconds left to the next controller when it's instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally use properties in Objective-C. But all in all you shouldn't have 21 xibs. You should have views, or better yet use Storyboard. Xibs are slowly becoming antiquated, moving to Storyboards is the trend. Also it's not recommended practice but you can store global variables in AppDelegate and make it publicly accessible in your entire project!

You could also use NSUserDefaults, persist data in CoreData, use SQLLite database, persist data to a file, etc, etc.

There are many different ways to skin this cat.